# COUNT QUERY PHP

Tags: php, count

i want to get a count result. my query is like this

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(TRUE);

$query->select('COUNT(*)')->from('#__country')->where('status = "1" ');

$db->setQuery($query);

return $db->loadAssoc();
```

Comment: Please provide necessary info about the framework that you are using for DAL. Are you getting any errors? Your query looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Joomla, right? So to count the results you can try the following,

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$result_count = $db->query();
$result_count = $db->getNumRows();
```

Hope this will help you!